# Php Mysql SELECT query 1 column equals 1 variable

Tags: php, mysql, variables, select, where-clause

I've been throw so many threads for 4+ hours here and abroad and seem to be missing a simple thing.

I'm trying to have several users upload their 'news' to MYSQL.
Yet I want to display only the 'news' with the logged in username (userpost) attached to the row.
$current is the username for who is logged in, which works.
Example A isn't filtering out rows that don't contain the $current user.
Example B isn't providing any output

So I've tried both A:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM images_tbl");
//echo $current . "2" . $current;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    if ($row['userpost'] = '.$current.') {
    $num = 0;
    $num = $num + 1;
    $pic.$num = $row['images_path'];
    $h1 = $row['hlone'];
```

and B:

```
 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM images_tbl WHERE (userpost = '.$current.')");
    echo $current . "2" . $current;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo $row['hlone'] . " " . $row['images_path'];
      echo "<img src=\"" .$row['images_path']. "\">";
    }
```

27, images/08-10-2014-1412752801.jpg(images_path), 2014-10-08, Headline(hlone), Headline2, story, testb(userpost)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show your database model

Answer (score 1):

Add where clause to your query

```
//in situation A
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM images_tbl where username='".$current."'");
//username is column name for user you might have to change this
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['images_path'];
    echo $row['hlone'];
}
```

In situation B try this

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM images_tbl WHERE userpost = '".$current."')");
    echo $current . "2" . $current;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo $row['hlone'] . " " . $row['images_path'];
      echo "<img src=\"" .$row['images_path']. "\">";
    }
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I've tried everyone's suggestions again and again, it still can't echo any info from the database...

There are so many variations of the WHERE statement I've tried and can't figure out for the life of me why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to filter with PHP.

If you want to filter the 'news' that have not written by current user just use MySQL Where clause:

```
// For Example A
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM images_tbl WHERE userpost != '{$current}'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $pic = $row['images_path'];
    $h1 = $row['hlone'];
}

// For Example B
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM images_tbl WHERE userpost = '{$current}')");
echo $current . "2" . $current;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['hlone'] . " " . $row['images_path'];
    echo "<img src=\"" .$row['images_path']. "\">";
}
```

It's easy with MySQL's filtering options. You should do more research about MySQL.

Comment: Thanks guys for the effors, still no luck getting this to work.
I know PHP isn't the efficient way to do this, but it was worth a shot; Example A is the only one that is outputting anything from the database still, too bad it's outputting everything.

I've read for even more hours on Mysql, and have an OReilly Mysql book that just has a few short sentences on WHERE statements.

If anyone has any ideas or knows what else could be missing that'd be great.

Thanks so much for the help :)

Comment: It is a late answer but you said `$current` has the correct value. Yet again if its still gets all the data from DB, first check the `userpost` column of the table with phpMyAdmin and see if it has values. You need to do some debug yourself. If the query gets the results from DB, that means query working so we cannot get any error from MySQL. Something has to be wrong in `userpost` column.